# Not understanding the error given in Live SQL

Tags: oracle

I am simply Creating a table Class where I am inserting 2 students. I am just a beginner and writing a simple code in Oracle live SQL worksheet where I want to insert values and select it. But getting the same error everytime on writing this particular code.

```
CREATE TABLE Class
( 
  studentid int NOT NULL,
  studentname varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT ALL   
INTO Class(studentid,studentname) VALUES (1,'JIT') 
INTO Class(studentid,studentname) VALUES (2,'Joy') 
SELECT * FROM Class;
commit;
```

The error is:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
>
> Statement processed.

Where does the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create table` and `INSERT ALL`  statements you've written are syntactically correct. So, there's no reason why you should get that error.

One important point to note although is that you should use `varchar2` and not `varchar` in Oracle.

The `INSERT ALL` statement won't insert anything because there are no rows yet in the table just after it's created. The source  select statement doesn't return anything. For it to work, you could change the table in the select statement to `dual`.

```
INSERT ALL

  INTO Class(studentid,studentname) VALUES (1,'JIT')

  INTO Class(studentid,studentname) VALUES (2,'Joy')

SELECT * FROM dual;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a4f924de7496a2b11e9110fb14dcd0d)